# A marble is drawn from a box containing $10$ red, $30$ white, $20$ blue and $15$ orange marbles.

Tags: probability, statistics

A marble is drawn from a box containing $10$ red, $30$ white, $20$ blue and $15$ orange marbles. What is the probability that it is neither a red nor a blue marble. Express your answer as a rational number with denominator equal to the lowest common factor. a Little help here

Edit to include attempt:

Given $75$ marbles totally. I'm interested in the probability that the marble i get is neither red or blue. I come up with $\frac35$. Given $45$ are the white and orange marbles, the probability that I draw a marble that is not clue or red is $\frac35$. Am I correct? its sounds to easy tho

Comment: do you want to tell us where do you get stuck?

Comment: Given 75 marbles totally. I'm interested in the probability that the marble i get is neither red or blue. I come up with 3/5. Given 45 are the white and orange marbles, the probability that I draw a marble that is not clue or red is 3/5. Am I correct? its sounds to easy tho

Comment: congrats. you are right.  thank you for sharing your thought.  usually sharing your thoughts and your attempt will obtain more positive response on this site.  Welcome to math stack exchange.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anywhere i can rate you or something like that?

Comment: You can accept an anwer if it helps. when your reputation hits $15$, you can upvote an answer as well.

Answer (score 1):

If a marble is neither red nor blue. It must be either white or orange.

Your answer is correct.

$$\frac{45}{75}=\frac{3}{5}$$